# Gdiplus compile time errors in my cpp library

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, gdi+

I'm trying to use `Gdiplus` library `in my C++ library` in `visual studio 2022`. Before compiling I tested my codes in a c++ code `with main function` and it `works`. the code is here:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <Unknwn.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ObjIdl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment( lib, "gdiplus.lib" )

cv::Mat to_mat(Gdiplus::Bitmap& image)
{ // my codes }

HRESULT GetGdiplusEncoderClsid(const std::wstring& format, GUID* pGuid)
{ // my codes }

int main()
{ // my codes }
```

But when I tried to use it in my library, I faced with lots of errors. I searched a lot and now I'm suspicious of order of `order of #includes or namespace collision`. Here is my library `header (.h)`:

```
#pragma once

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

#include <opencv2\core.hpp>

#include <INIReader.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <filesystem>
#include <math.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <numeric>


#include <Unknwn.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ObjIdl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace Gdiplus;

#pragma comment( lib, "gdiplus.lib" )

namespace utl
{ // bunch of free function codes }
```

and here is `.cpp` codes of my library:

```
#include "pch.h"
#define getCurrentDir _getcwd
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

#include "Util.h"

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

#include <direct.h>
#include <libloaderapi.h>
#include <numeric>
#include <functional>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <format>
#include <corecrt_math_defines.h>
#include <codecvt>

#include <Unknwn.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ObjIdl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

using namespace std;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using namespace cv;

using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment( lib, "gdiplus.lib" )
```

and here is several of errors in visual studio:

[image: compile time errors is VS]

almost all of the errors are caused by `std::max` and `std::min` in different place any used library. here is an example of the errors:

[image: an example of the errors]

How can I fix it?
and why does it happen it me?

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](/questions/13416418/define-nominmax-using-stdmin-max).

Comment: *Don't* use `using namespace ` inside a header file!

Comment: `#define NOMINMAX` to the rescue!

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know that. I just tried to find out if it works